# No se muestra ImageView al emular la aplicación

Tags: java, android, android-studio

Quiero añadir dos `ImageView` a mi `layout`. En la **Preview** de Android Studio se muestran correctamente las imágenes con la `API 22` pero al emular la aplicación en mi móvil de API 22 las imágenes no se ven. Utilizo la ultima versión de Android Studio y no encuentro el motivo de porque no se muestran correctamente las imágenes.

```
    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:layout_width="wrap_content"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:weightSum="1"
android:id="@+id/cont">

<ScrollView
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
    android:focusable="true"
    android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
    android:id="@+id/scroll">

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
        android:focusable="true"
        android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
        android:id="@+id/total">

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="288dp"
            android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
            android:focusable="true"
            android:focusableInTouchMode="true"
            android:id="@+id/form">

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_width="200dp"
                android:layout_marginTop="90dp"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
                android:layout_marginLeft="100dp"
                android:scrollbarSize="20dp"
                android:id="@+id/usu"
                android:descendantFocusability="beforeDescendants"
                android:focusableInTouchMode="true">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Correo"
                    android:inputType="textEmailAddress"
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:id="@+id/correo" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <android.support.v7.widget.Toolbar
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:background="?attr/colorPrimary"
                android:theme="?attr/actionBarTheme"
                android:minHeight="?attr/actionBarSize"
                android:id="@+id/toolbar"
                android:layout_weight="0.13" />

            <android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                app:hintTextAppearance="@style/TextLabel"
                android:id="@+id/co"
                android:layout_marginTop="25dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/usu"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/usu"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/usu">

                <EditText
                    android:layout_width="200dp"
                    android:layout_height="match_parent"
                    android:hint="Contraseña"
                    android:layout_above="@+id/textInputLayout"
                    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
                    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
                    android:layout_weight="1"
                    android:id="@+id/pass" />
            </android.support.design.widget.TextInputLayout>

            <ImageView
                android:layout_width="50dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/key"
                android:id="@+id/imageView3"
                android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/co"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp" />

            <ImageView
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                app:srcCompat="@drawable/user"
                android:layout_marginRight="16dp"
                android:layout_marginEnd="16dp"
                android:id="@+id/imageView2"
                android:layout_above="@+id/co"
                android:layout_toLeftOf="@+id/co"
                android:layout_toStartOf="@+id/co"
                android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
                android:layout_width="50dp" />

        </RelativeLayout>

        <RelativeLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="248dp">

            <Button
                android:text="Entrar"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/login"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="#CDDC39"
                android:id="@+id/entrar"
                android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
                android:layout_marginTop="26dp" />

            <TextView
                android:text="Aun no eres usuario?"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:id="@+id/textView"
                android:textSize="20sp"
                android:layout_centerVertical="true"
                android:layout_centerHorizontal="true" />

            <Button
                android:text="Registrate"
                android:layout_height="50dp"
                android:drawableLeft="@drawable/account"
                android:id="@+id/registro"
                android:textColor="@android:color/white"
                android:backgroundTint="#CDDC39"
                android:layout_weight="0.13"
                android:layout_width="150dp"
                android:layout_below="@+id/textView"
                android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/entrar"
                android:layout_alignStart="@+id/entrar"
                android:layout_marginTop="30dp" />


        </RelativeLayout>
    </LinearLayout>
</ScrollView>
```

styles.xml

```
    <resources>
<!-- Base application theme. -->
<style name="AppTheme.Base" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light.NoActionBar">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#CDDC39</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#AFB42B</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">#FFC107</item>

</style>
<style name="AppTheme" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>
<style name="AppTheme.Base2" parent="Theme.AppCompat.Light">

    <item name="colorPrimary">#CDDC39</item>

    <item name="colorPrimaryDark">#AFB42B</item>

    <item name="colorAccent">#518B05</item>

</style>
<style name="AppTheme2" parent="AppTheme.Base"></style>
<style name="TextLabel" parent="TextAppearance.Design.Hint">
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
</resources>
```

AndroidManifest.xml

```
   <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
```

```
<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:hardwareAccelerated="false"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme"
    >
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Sesion.Registro"

        android:parentActivityName=".Sesion.Login">
        <meta-data
            android:name="android.support.PARENT_ACTIVITY"
            android:value=".Sesion.Login" />
    </activity>
    <activity android:name=".Sesion.Login"
        android:windowSoftInputMode="stateUnspecified">
    </activity>

</application>
```

Login.java

```
    import android.app.Activity;
    import android.content.Intent;
    import android.os.Bundle;
    import android.support.annotation.NonNull;
    import android.util.Log;
    import android.view.View;
    import android.widget.Button;
    import android.widget.EditText;
    import android.widget.Toast;

    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnCompleteListener;
    import com.google.android.gms.tasks.Task;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.AuthResult;
    import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
    import com.libreria.conxi.proyecto.R;

    import static android.content.ContentValues.TAG;



    public class Login extends Activity {
private FirebaseAuth mAuth;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.login);

    mAuth = FirebaseAuth.getInstance();

    //Boton para dirigir a la Activity de Registro
    Button btn2 = (Button) findViewById(R.id.registro);
    btn2.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent2 = new Intent (v.getContext(), Registro.class);
            startActivityForResult(intent2, 0);
        }
    });

    //Boton para entrar en el usuario
    Button btn = (Button) findViewById(R.id.entrar);
    btn.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            EditText correo = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.correo);
            EditText pass = (EditText) findViewById(R.id.pass);


            String email=correo.getText().toString();
            String password=pass.getText().toString();

            if (email.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter email address!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            if (password.equals("")) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Enter password!", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                return;
            }

            mAuth.signInWithEmailAndPassword(email, password)
                    .addOnCompleteListener(Login.this, new OnCompleteListener<AuthResult>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<AuthResult> task) {

                            if (!task.isSuccessful()) {
                                // there was an error
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication failed.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            } else {
                                Log.w(TAG, "signInWithEmail", task.getException());
                                Toast.makeText(Login.this, "Authentication success.",
                                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                            }
                        }
                    });
                        }
    });
}
    }
```

¿ Alguna idea para solucionar este problema ?

Comment: deberías añadir la clase asociada a tu XML

Comment: no se si ya logro solucionar el inconveniente, les voy a decir lo que a mi me funciono, solamente cambie las imagenes de carpeta desde la drawable a la carpeta mipmap y listo se soluciono sin mas inconvenientes.

Answer (score 1):

Cuando usas   `app:srcCompat="@drawable/user"`, debes definir: `android:background="@mipmap/user"` esta propiedad de esta manera podrás cargar el recurso, no tiene sentido para mi... pero es la única forma que logre solventar el problema

Answer (score 1):

Porqué no usas `android:src="@drawable/user"` directamente en lugar de `app:srcCompat="@drawable/user"` ?

Answer (score 1):

Si estas usando propiedades de las clases de soporte tu Activity debe extender de `AppCompatActivity`

Si usas vector assets, que tienen esta estructura:

```
<vector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
 ...
 ...
</vector>
```

puedes usar :

```
 app:srcCompat="@drawable/..."
```

de otra forma si son imágenes de formato .png, .jpg usa simplemente :

```
 android:src="@drawable/..."
```

Answer (score 0):

Prueba lo siguiente:

```
public class Login extends Activity
```

En esta linea de tu java, debes poner:

```
public class Login extends AppCompatActivity
```